# Animate between states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, transition, framer-motion

I have the following code, where I switch between some divs depending on state:

```
import React from 'react'    
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const App= props => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  const components = [
    <div>
        <p>Slide 1</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Next</button>
    </div>,

    <div>
        <p>Slide 2</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Prev</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Next</button>
    </div>,

    <div>
        <p>Slide 3</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Prev</button>
    </div>,
  ]

  return (
    <>
      {components[count]}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Currently they just appear, as intended, but I would like some kind of transition. Slide in, fade in, I don't know. How can this be done between states ? Framer Motion, CSS Transitions ?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue on my project. And i fixed it by using state to toggle a class.
For example `<div className={this.state.showDiv ? "showDivClass" : "hideDivClass"}>`
In my css, `.showDivClass` has a `display:block;` property , and `.hideDivClass` has a `display:none;` property.

**changing the state, will now toggle visibility** But not yet animate anything at all.
To make this happen. i simply added an animation property I needed in the CSS selector that shows the div. For example

```
.showDivClass{
   display:block;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
}
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: But you can't really animate `display: none` can you ? At least only one way.

Comment: using keyframes you could. also depending on the type of animation you want, you could make it animate going left, right, up, or down, using the width and height property